# Solving for the base of a modular exponent for El Gamal cryptosystem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

We are given $B \equiv g^b \mod p$ and the values for $B,b,p$ but not $g$.

How  can we determine $g$ from the knowledge of $p, b$ and $B$,
provided that $\gcd(b, p − 1) = 1$.

The only solution that I can come up with is finding all of the primitive roots of $p$ and then brute forcing the solution but there must be an easier way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since $b$ and $p-1$ are relatively prime, you can find $u,v$ such that  $ub+v(p-1)=1$.  you have $g=g^{ub+v(p-1)} = g^{ub}$ mod $p$. Here I use little fermat theorem which says that $g^{p-1}=1$. So given $B,u$, you have just to compute $B^u=g^{ub}=g$ mod $p$.

Comment: I understand how you used fermats little theorum to obtain g=g^ub but how does this lead you to the fact that B^v=g^ub mod p